# How to create a record without using a model in go-gorm (struct) ? I can able to retrive records , But to create it?

Tags: go, go-gorm

golang gorm allows us to retrive (or) update records without creating models and using `map[string]interface{}{}`. But how to create a record without using a model ?

Comment: No, gorm don't provide and it's valid because you can't provide type of column then

Comment: this don't make any sense actually.